# entity Framework : Model.edmx modifications are lost when update model from database

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, edmx

I'm using Entity Framework with database First and I have created model.edmx from an existing database on SQL server.
Now for some reasons I made some changes in the model.
For example I implemented InotiFyPropertyChanged and on some classes I have changed the original code generated by wizard.
But when I change something on database , I update the model from database , all the changes made for implementing the above feature are lost , and I have to write from beginning all the changes.
Is there any way to preserve these changes when update the model from database ?
Or another way how to resolve this problem ?
Thank you !

**Updated :**

This is the original class generated by wizard :

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Partial Public Class Myobj1
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property prc As Decimal
    Public Property categ As Integer
End Class
```

This is the class with changes :

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel

Partial Public Class Myobj1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Property id As Integer

Private privatprc As Decimal
    Public Property prc() As Decimal
    Get
        Return privatprc
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        privatprc = value
        OnPropertyChanged("prc")
    End Set
End Property

Private privatcateg As Integer
    Public Property categ() As Integer
       Get
           Return privatcateg
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            privatcateg = value
            OnPropertyChanged("categ")
        End Set
    End Property

 Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyc As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyc))
    End Sub
End Class
```

What should I do ?

**Update :
I create a separate class file with this content :**

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports MyProg.MyObj1

   <MetadataType(GetType(MyObj1MetaData))> Partial Public Class Myobj1
Friend NotInheritable Class Myobj1MetaData
  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged
Private privatprc As Decimal
    Public Property prc() As Decimal
    Get
        Return privatprc
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        privatprc = value
        OnPropertyChanged("prc")
    End Set
End Property

Private privatcateg As Integer
    Public Property categ() As Integer
       Get
           Return privatcateg
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            privatcateg = value
            OnPropertyChanged("categ")
        End Set
    End Property

 Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyc As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyc))
    End Sub
End Class
 End Class
```

Everything run without any error , but the problem is that the feature that I want to implement ( OnPropertyChanged ) is not implemented and it seems that this new class has no effect.
What can I do ?
Thank you !

Answer (score -2):

Check out this link http://forums.asp.net/t/1885808.aspx?Update+edmx+file+without+effecting+currently+generated+model
You might want to take a look at ryanbesko 's answer. The partial class gets an attribute that points it towards a metadata class. Sorry for the messy code. I don't have access to VS. This is just to give you a basic idea:

```
<MetadataType(GetType(MyObj1Metadata))> 
    Public Partial Class MyObj1
    //your class code generated from ef goes here

    End Class
Public Class MyObj1Metadata

<Required(ErrorMessage := "Property is required.")> 
Private privatprc As Decimal
    Public Property prc() As Decimal
    Get
        Return privatprc
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        privatprc = value
        OnPropertyChanged("prc")
    End Set
End Property
// don't add any new code here, just match what is in your model classes and add data annotations to them.

End Class
```

Comment: The point is any changes you make to the classes with the edmx file will be wiped out once you update your model.

Comment: Please , can you give me some help how can I implement the idea on the link in my specific case , on my first post updated ? Thank you !

Comment: <MetadataType(GetType(MyObj1Metadata))>  this tag will be above the partial class.  Didn't show up in the answer.

Comment: Sorry , but what is the connection between 2 classes because Public class Myobj1Metadata seems a new class that is not related with the class generated by wizard.

Comment: Myobj1Metadata class will be in the same namespace as that of the EF generated class and you will match it to them. Any other functinality will be added to the partial class Myobj1. This is the way to implement your question as if you make changes to the classes connected to edmx directly your changes won't be maintained in ef (drawbacks of using model first approach). this approach is a workaround.

Comment: Not having access to Visual Studio is not an excuse for not formatting your code.

Comment: @Syed Sorry but if these classes are in the same place so inside Model1.edmx , when I update my model from database all these data will be cleared and after only the original class generated by wizard will exist.

Comment: @Syed : Please see my last update on my post , because I follow your suggestion on the link , but it seems that doesn't work.Thank you !

Comment: You  keep these classes outside the edmx. Even the model.tt files I.e the pocos generated from the db first can be moved and kept outside of it if you remove their dependency on the model. That way any changes you make will remain even if the model is updated.

Comment: @ I found a better solution for your prob. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28818721/4282901