# Preserving changes to my models when updating from database?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am using EF to generate my models using the Model.context.tt template as [described in this post.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx)

After my models have been generated I would like to go in and make some modifications to the models.  I am able to do this, but the problem that I am running into is that if I update my model from the database it will overwrite any customization that I have done.

Is there any way to preserve the changes that I have made to my models while still updating from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create partial classes, with exactly the same name, and in the same namespace as the generated models, you will then be able to modify the class without loosing the changes each time the T4 template gets regenerated.

If you need more finer tuned editing of the original class you have to edit the .tt Template. Although I would **HIGHLY** recommend looking into Code First (which is more than possible against an existing database) as you have full control of the class + mappings.

You could possibly start by copying the currently generated files and using them as your basis for the code first model.

A common misconception is that Code First is not for Existing Database/ Database First work because of the name. But this is not true.

- **Code First** = Writing code and decorating models with attributes or
  custom mappings in the Context.
- **EDMX / Designer** = Using the Visual Studio designer to create an XML(.edmx) which then gets processed by a T4(.tt) template to generate your final classes + context. *Personally I find this method very painful, as I constantly loose changes (custom mappings/relationships etc)*
- **Entity Migrations** - this is where you write your code first, identical to the *"Code First"* approach above, but you then run Migrations in order to generate and upgrade/downgrade a database.

Comment: Code First seems like it might be a good option for me at this point.  How hard is it to convert from Database First to Code First?  Can you recommend any reading regarding this switch?

Comment: Also - the changes that I make will eventually need to be replicated to the Production database server.  I'm assuming it possible to update the database from my project without loosing all the data?